# How do I change the text color in my legend, in Stata 'twoway'?

Tags: stata

My colleague created a graph in Stata using the code below. I'd like to make the writing "By eliminating lead" in the legend appear blue, like the writing of 'hlo_expost1'. How do I achieve this? Thanks!

```
#delimit ;
        tw  (pccapsym rank hlo  rank hlo_expost1, msym(none) lcolor(blue))
            (sc rank hlo, mlabel(hlos1) msymbol(none) mlabpos(9))
            (sc rank hlo_expost1, mlabel(effect1s1) msymbol(none) mlabpos(3) mlabc(blue))
            (sc rank left, mlabel(countryname) msymbol(none) mlabpos(3) mlabcolor(black)),
            ysc(off) xsc(range(650)) 
            legend(order(2 "Status quo" 3 "By eliminating lead"))
            ylab(,nogrid) xlab(0(100)600,nogrid)
            xline(500)
            xsize(4) ysize(6)
            xtitle("World Bank, Harmonized Learning Outcomes", margin(20 0 0 0) height(5))
        ;   
    #delimit cr
```

I've tried many options in the legend() option, but none have worked so far.

Comment: You can change text colours one by one in the Graph Editor. I have not found a way to do with syntax.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1716761-how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-text-in-my-legend-in-twoway